# Tcl: error when using sed command

Tags: regex, sed, tcl

My string is like following :

> str1.str2.strn-1.{i}.strn

I use the `sed` command to remove the the string after the last dot '.'

```
proc check_str {str} {

set cmd "echo $str | sed -E 's/[^.]+$//'"

set new_str [exec sh -c $cmd]
puts "the new string is :$new_str"
}
```

But I got error:

> invalid command name ^.

and the new string is not displayed!

How can I display the new string?

Comment: Surely to goodness Tcl/Tk provides mechanisms to handle regular expressions without requiring anything so clumsy as executing an external command to deal with it.

Comment: so what is the alternative solution with tcl ?

Comment: You've been asking a lot of fairly straightforward questions about string processing. I'd recommend you spend some time with [the Tcl tutorial](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/tcltutorial.html) and [the Tcl man pages](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/contents.htm) -- you'll soon be able to answer your own questions.

Answer (score 2):

The `regsub` command matches a regular-expression and applies a substitution to the matched text. It's very similar to what you do with sed's `s`.

```
set new_str [regsub {[^.]+$} $str ""]
```

Note that it's almost always important to put regular expressions in braces (which in Tcl are very much like single quotes in unix shells), because they typically contain Tcl metacharacters. In this case, the regular expression contains `[`, `]` and `$` (though in a terminal position); it needs to be quoted with or Tcl will try to execute the strangely-named command `^.` It could have also been quoted with backslashes, but that gets annoying and unclear.

And that was also what was wrong with your previous attempt in your question. Using an `exec sed` for this is utter overkill. Using `exec echo … | sed` is even worse, as is doing it from inside `sh -c`. The right tool is at hand, and is far more efficient (given that you're already in Tcl).

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution with tcl :

```
regsub -- {[^.]+$} $str {} string
```

Answer (score 1):

Another Tcl technique would be to split that string into a list of words, using dot as the separator. Replace the last word with an empty string. Join the words back together.

```tcl
set str {str1.str2.strn-1.{i}.strn}
set words [split $str .]
lset words end ""
set new [join $words .]   # => str1.str2.strn-1.{i}.
```

Yet another technique is to find the index of the last dot in the string. Then take the substring from zero to that index

```
set new [string range $str 0 [string last . $str]]
```

IMO even regsub is overkill for this task.

Comment: `regsub` is about 25% faster, even when pushing your version into maximally-compiled mode. But that `file rootname` version is much faster again; being ~275% faster than the `regexp` version and ~370% faster than yours.

Answer (score 1):

There is a command that does almost exactly what you want, except that it removes the last dot as well -- but that's easy to fix by adding a new dot at the end:

```
set new [file rootname $str].
# => str1.str2.strn-1.{i}.
```

Documentation: [file](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/file.htm)